# RewriteRule in .htaccess for directories destroys general 404 ErrorDocument and creates 500

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404

I added a RewriteRule to make the path of '/some-page' opening the '/some-page/index.php' but showing '/some-page/' in the browser's address bar. This works fine as expected.

On the other hand I have now the problem that whenever I type a not-existing path like e.g. '/this-does-not-exist.html' I am prompted a 500 message and not redirected to the 404 page anymore.

And if I type e.g. '/kontakt' I am prompted with an 404. But if I type '/kontakt.php' it works. It should show '/kontakt.php' if I type '/kontakt' and should show '/kontakt' in the browser's address bar.

Here is the part of my .htacces:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
ErrorDocument 503 /503.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Normally you would do something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?args=$1 [L]`.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I tried your RewriteRule. But it redirects every request to index.php. Even for js files.

Comment: Is this in a .htaccess file (in httpdocs)? There it should work properly. If you changed in vhost.config you need to restart apache. `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should grant files will pass thru.